# Can I print list data in a more elegant way?

Tags: python, list, printing, coding-style

Is there a cleaner way to structure my print function?

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
    }
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
    }
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
    }

students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]

for student in students:
    print student["name"]
    print student["homework"]
    print student["quizzes"]
    print student["tests"]
```

I tried the following piece of code but got a syntax error:

```
for student in students:
    print student["name", "homework", "quizzes", "tests"]
```

I apologize if this has already been answered, but I couldn't find the question.

Comment: Do you want the information all on the same line?

Comment: Do you need them in a particular order? How about `for student in student: for key in ('name', ...): print student[key]`?

Comment: No, I would like for it to be printed out like in the first example, but without writing print multiple times. 
Actually, yes, I'm curious to know how I could also print it out in one line. It's just that the task requires me to print it out in rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use a second `for` loop:

```
for student in students:
    for x in ("name", "homework", "quizzes", "tests"):
        print student[x]
```

Comment: Does the order matter? You can just use `student.values()` because each student dictionary is hashed the same way, so the values will correspond and align, though the values is not necessarily in an order.

Comment: The order does matter, yes. Appreciate your answer as well though.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass each dict to [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) accessing [arguments by name](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples):

```
for student in students:
    print("{name}\n{homework}\n{quizzes}\n{tests}".format(**student))
```

Output:

```
Lloyd
[90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0]
[88.0, 40.0, 94.0]
[75.0, 90.0]
Alice
[100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0]
[82.0, 83.0, 91.0]
[89.0, 97.0]
Tyler
[0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0]
[0.0, 75.0, 78.0]
[100.0, 100.0]
```